# Copying s3 file to ec2 every time file posted to bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to automatically copy s3 files to an ec2 instance when something is added to the bucket. What is the best way to do this? I'm pretty sure that I can create a Lambda event trigger every time something is added to the bucket, and have a Lambda function perform an aws cli command, but is there another/better way to do this? I would have to figure out how to detect the latest file added and only add that one.

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? Is it important that the file is copied _immediately_? Have you considered having a script on the Amazon EC2 instance **pull** files on a regular basis, instead of **pushing** them to the instance? Can you tell us more about how the files will be used?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need to transfer the files to another machine once copied to the instance

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Oh, how can I get the EC2 instance to pull files from s3? How would that be different/better than copying it to the instance? And to pull on a regular basis, are you thinking a cron job, or were you referring to another method?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this would need to be automated! My objective is to *not need to specify the file manually*.

Comment: You could have a cron job run `aws s3 sync` on a regular basis, which would synchronize the contents of the S3 bucket with the files on the instance. Or, you could have S3 push the event to an SQS queue and a cron-triggered script on the instance checks for messages and downloads the files. Or, have S3 trigger a Lambda function that triggers a Systems Manager Run Command that executes a 'download' command on the instance. The choice of method would depend on the urgency of the download (must it be immediate?) and the number of files (too many to sync?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of AWS Lambda and [Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), as follows:

- write a Lambda function triggered by the upload to S3
- have the Lambda function call Run Command to run a remote script on the relevant EC2 instance(s) which will cause the file to be downloaded from S3 onto the EC2 instance

One additional advantage of this approach is that you could easily use it to sync the new S3 object to multiple EC2 instances, identified by tags.

Comment: This sounds like the idea I mentioned in my initial question. You're saying to create an S3 event that sends a notification to a Lambda function when something is added to the bucket, and then have the Lambda function run an aws cli command to copy/ download the file to EC2 when it gets an event notification right?

Comment: The key addition here is the use of Systems Manager Run Command. That is the glue that allows you run arbitrary scripts on an arbitrary set of EC2 instances. Lambda cannot directly run an awscli sync or copy directly on EC2, of course.

Comment: Oh, interesting, so I would run SSM agent in my Lambda function?

Comment: No, SSM agent runs on your EC2 instances. That's a pre-requisite for this to work, so check if that's true (or install it as needed). It's [pre-installed on certain AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/install-ssm-agent-ec2-linux/). In Lambda, you would make API calls to the SSM service via your AWS SDK of choice (e.g. boto3) and the SSM service would trigger the requested EC2 instances to run your script of choice (the SSM service talks to the SSM agents running on EC2).

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you by any chance know if I would be able to automatically upload the *latest* added file? Would I have to specify a specific file name each time? If not, no worries. Thanks.

Comment: If by "latest added file" you mean the file that actually triggered the Lambda in the first place, then yes. Your Lambda function is invoked with the bucket and key of the S3 object that was just uploaded, so you can take that information and provide it in parameters to the script that you're going to ask SSM to run on the EC2 instances. That script can be whatever you want - it could simply use the awscli to copy the new S3 object down to the instance, or sync from the bucket, or whatever it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since recently, Lambda also supports EFS [1], so you can configure your Lambda function to copy files from S3 to EFS every time something is added to the bucket.
And then read those files from EFS in your EC2 instance.

[1] - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/aws-lambda-support-for-amazon-elastic-file-system-now-generally-/

Comment: Hm, that would be adding an extra step. Is there a reason why I should do this instead of just having the lambda function copy the files to the instance, or just having the instance pull from s3?

Comment: Based on the description you provided you want to have a file copied from s3 to ec2 every time that file is updated in the bucket. Lambda cannot directly copy an object from s3 to ec2 (unless you use some kind of ssh to get into an instance), but lambda can copy file to efs from where ec2 can read a file. Or I did not understand your intention?

Comment: I mean that the Lambda function would be executing an aws cli command to copy the files, as if it were being done through the console :o If I'm not mistaken, there is a way to install the dependencies so that the aws cli can be used via a Lambda function :)

Comment: interesting... you can definetely install aws cli as a lambda layer like this - https://bezdelev.com/hacking/aws-cli-inside-lambda-layer-aws-s3-sync/

but, I'm still do not understand how aws cli can help you with loading files to ec2... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure **S3 event notification** on the S3 bucket to achieve this. Choose the `event notification destination` as `Lambda Function`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

Comment: Yea, that was what I planned on doing initially. I'm trying to see if there is another/better way though.

Comment: Using native tools/features is always better as you know :)